# How to compare 2 array and add key if don't have

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

Supposed that I have two arrays to compare:

```
var arrOriginal={currency1: 1234, currency2: 2345};
var arrToCompare={currency1: 123};
```

I was trying to find the difference between the two.

Example result:

```
var result={currency1: 1111, currency2: 2345}
```

What I've tried:
Using `for .. in` and then substract.

```
for (var key in this.arrOriginal) {
  this.result.push({
    currency: key,
    amount: format.formatCurrency(this.arrToCompare[key] - this.arrOriginal[key])
  });
}
```

But it won't show the currency key which the second array don't have.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take a default value of zero for `undefined` properties of the object.

From inside to out:

- Get entries from the object as an array of key/value pairs.
- Map this entries and get an object with the key and a value of the difference of value and the corresponding value of the other object or zero.
- Spread the object as parameters for [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).
- And get a new object with all objects from mapping.

```js
var original = { currency1: 1234, currency2: 2345 },
    deltas = { currency1: 123 },
    result = Object.assign(
        {},
        ...Object.entries(original).map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v - (deltas[k] || 0)}))
    );

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

A very simple approach is looping over the keys of `arrOriginal`, If that key is present in `arrToCompare` then substract that value else do not substract.

```js
var arrOriginal={currency1: 1234, currency2: 2345};
var arrToCompare={currency1: 123};

var out = {}
for(var key in arrOriginal){
 out[key] = arrOriginal[key] - (arrToCompare[key] || 0)
}

console.log(out)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.entries` and `reduce`

```js
var arrOriginal={currency1: 1234, currency2: 2345};
var arrToCompare={currency1: 123};

let final = Object.entries(arrOriginal).reduce((op,[key,value])=>{
  op[key] = value - (arrToCompare[key] || 0)
  return op
},{})

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 1):

A very easy to understand approach would be to have an if-else statement with three branches that check if the key exists in both or either one of the original objects:

```js
const original = { currency1: 1234, currency2: 2345 }
const toCompare = { currency1: 123 }
const result = {}
const allKeys = new Set(Object.keys(original).concat(Object.keys(toCompare)))
allKeys.forEach(k => {
  if (k in original && k in toCompare) {
    result[k] = original[k] - toCompare[k]
  } else if (k in original) {
    result[k] = original[k]
  } else {
    result[k] = toCompare[k]
  }
})
console.log(result)
```